# Angular 4 : Custom validator not being called

Tags: angular, validation, angular-directive

I have defined a custom validator for pan card number validation(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_account_number).

```
function validatePan(): ValidatorFn {

 return (c: AbstractControl) => {   
            var regpan = /^([a-zA-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([a-zA-Z]){1}?$/;

            if (!regpan.test(c.value)) {
                return {
                    validatepan: {
                      valid: false
                    }
                  };
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
}        

@Directive({
 selector: '[validatepan][ngModel], [validatepan][formControlName],    [validatepan][formControl]',
   providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => PanValidator),     multi: true }
   ]
})
export class PanValidator implements Validator{
    validator: ValidatorFn;

  constructor() {
    this.validator = validatePan();
  }

  validate(c: FormControl) {
    console.log('here');
    return this.validator(c);
  }

}
```

I have registered the Directive in the declarations section of the module

```
 declarations: [
        ....
        PanValidator
   ],
```

I am using the directive as follows

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="testpan" id="field_testpan"
            [(ngModel)]="testval.testpan"
        validatepan />
```

But it is neither initializing the directive nor calling the validate function.

Comment: in your validatePan function, your are return a ValidatorFn, whose type should be a ValidatorErrors. But in your function, it nothing. Try adding return type of ValidatorError in your Validaton function;

Answer (score 6):

I was able to figure out the issue. When I added the validator to the exports section the functionality worked seemlessly.

```
exports: [
    ....
    PanValidator
],
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why this works. I have a AppModule and MyModule structure. Simply declaring via AppModule won't work. I had to declare inside my child module. This is super strange.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem recently. Originally, I had just *AppModule*, where I declared both eg. SignupComponent and few validators which I used there to validate email etc. But then, I decided to move the SignupComponent and others to separate lazy loaded *FeatureModule* **but forgot about the validators**, which were still declared in the *AppModule*. I got no errors, some validators were even working - which was extremely confusing, but never ever was their `validate` method called.

So the solution was of course to declare them in *FeatureModule* instead of in *AppModule*. In Angular, you can declare service in the root module and they are accessible everywhere, but the validator directives (as all directives) need to be **declared** or **imported** to the module where they are being used. So if you plan on using them in other modules also, simply export them from the module (using `exports` property) as already suggested in the top answer and import the module where you need them.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Directive({
 selector: '[validatepan][ngModel],
   providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: PanValidator, multi: true }
   ]
})
```

Try changing the directive decorator like above.

More on Validator on Forms [LINK](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/template)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this as well. But the same result.

Comment: @PrashanthRaghu can you create plunker , that link has a working eample please follow that might help